# Agrupamiento en Consulta SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

**Buenos Días.**

He tenido problemas con la siguiente consulta:

> Mostrar todos los datos relacionados con el docto, dependiendo de la
> última fecha del documento, agregando el número de registros por
> documento que se tienen en total

[image: Registros]

```
SELECT MAX(id_seq) as UltimoIdSeq,docto as Documento, COUNT(docto) as NumeroDeRegistros, MAX(fdocto) as UltimaFechaDocto, MAX(nombre) as UltimoNombre, MAX(RFC) as UltimoRFC
FROM t_base
GROUP BY docto
ORDER BY NumeroDeRegistros DESC
```

Intenté hacerlo de esa manera pero el MAX simplemente me busca el último registro del alfabeto, no como tal el último registro.

Al final haciéndolo de manera manual la salida sería ésta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho si me pudieran apoyar.

**Saludos y buen día.**

Comment: Qué BD específicamente? Diferentes BD tienen diferentes features que pueden ayudar a resolver ese problema de diferentes formas.

Comment: Buen dia alex, es en sql (server ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es mostrar la fila de cada `docto` con el mayor `id_seq` para ese `docto`, añadiendo el número de registros total para ese `docto`.

Si conseguimos añadir a tu tabla el `max_id_seq` de cada `docto`, ya lo tenemos. Para obtener el número de registros habría que sumar agrupando por `max_id_seq` y `docto`, y para obtener la fila seleccionar por `id_seq=max_id_seq`.

Para añadir la columna `max_id_seq` tenemos que hacer un `JOIN` con esta tabla:

```
SELECT MAX(id_seq) AS max_id_seq, docto FROM t_base group by docto;

+------------+--------------------+
| max_id_seq | docto              |
+------------+--------------------+
|     606207 | EIVC98745-245      |
|     600305 | JMZN987O87-987456A |
|     600205 | RDAC9871-874446    |
+------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Así es como podemos hacer el `JOIN` con esta tabla para poder agrupar y hacer la suma:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.max_id_seq FROM t_base t1
JOIN   (SELECT MAX(id_seq) AS max_id_seq, docto FROM t_base group by docto) t2
       ON t1.docto = t2.docto;

+--------+---------------+-----+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+-----+-----------+------------+
| id_seq | status        | Aut | docto              | fdocto     | nombre             | rfc      | imp | descarea  | max_id_seq |
+--------+---------------+-----+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+-----+-----------+------------+
| 606133 | Pago a plazos | LLA | EIVC98745-245      | 2008-09-30 | Cristian Enríquez  | EIVC981  | 700 | Nayarit   |     606207 |
| 606134 | Pago a plazos | LLA | EIVC98745-245      | 2008-09-30 | Cristian Enríquez  | EIVC981  | 700 | Nayarit   |     606207 |
| 606135 | Pago a plazos | LLA | EIVC98745-245      | 2008-09-30 | Cristian Enríquez  | EIVC981  | 700 | Nayarit   |     606207 |
| 606136 | Pago a plazos | LLA | EIVC98745-245      | 2008-09-17 | Cristian Enríquez  | EIVC981  | 500 | Nayarit   |     606207 |
| 606137 | Pago a plazos | LLA | EIVC98745-245      | 2008-09-17 | Cristian Enríquez  | EIVC981  | 500 | Nayarit   |     606207 |
| 606207 | Pago a plazos | LLA | EIVC98745-245      | 2008-09-17 | Cristian Enríquez  | EIVC981  | 500 | Nayarit   |     606207 |
| 600200 | Pago a plazos | SSA | RDAC9871-874446    | 2008-09-30 | Manuel Rodríguez   | RDAC987  | 700 | Queretaro |     600205 |
| 600202 | Pago a plazos | SSA | RDAC9871-874446    | 2008-09-30 | Manuel Rodríguez   | RDAC987  | 700 | Queretaro |     600205 |
| 600203 | Pago a plazos | SSA | RDAC9871-874446    | 2008-09-17 | Manuel Rodríguez   | RDAC987  | 500 | Queretaro |     600205 |
| 600204 | Pago a plazos | SSA | RDAC9871-874446    | 2008-09-17 | Manuel Rodríguez   | RDAC987  | 500 | Queretaro |     600205 |
| 600205 | Pago a plazos | SSA | RDAC9871-874446    | 2008-09-17 | Manuel Rodríguez   | RDAC987  | 500 | Queretaro |     600205 |
| 600300 | Pago a plazos | DDA | JMZN987O87-987456A | 2008-09-30 | Juan Manzano       | JMZN987O | 700 | Monterrey |     600305 |
| 600303 | Pago a plazos | DDA | JMZN987O87-987456A | 2008-09-17 | Juan Manzano       | JMZN987O | 500 | Monterrey |     600305 |
| 600304 | Pago a plazos | DDA | JMZN987O87-987456A | 2008-09-17 | Juan Manzano       | JMZN987O | 500 | Monterrey |     600305 |
| 600305 | Pago a plazos | DDA | JMZN987O87-987456A | 2008-09-17 | Juan Manzano       | JMZN987O | 500 | Monterrey |     600305 |
+--------+---------------+-----+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+-----+-----------+------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

La suma de filas de cada doctor sería:

```
SELECT t2.max_id_seq, t1.docto, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM t_base t1
JOIN   (SELECT MAX(id_seq) AS max_id_seq, docto FROM t_base group by docto) t2
       ON t1.docto = t2.docto
GROUP  BY t2.max_id_seq, t1.docto;

+------------+--------------------+-----+
| max_id_seq | docto              | cnt |
+------------+--------------------+-----+
|     600205 | RDAC9871-874446    |   5 |
|     600305 | JMZN987O87-987456A |   4 |
|     606207 | EIVC98745-245      |   6 |
+------------+--------------------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ahora sólo nos queda hacer un `JOIN` de la tabla original con esta y seleccionar las filas en que `id_seq=max_id_seq`:

```
SELECT ta.*, tb.cnt
FROM   t_base ta
JOIN   (
    SELECT t2.max_id_seq, t1.docto, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM t_base t1
    JOIN   (SELECT MAX(id_seq) AS max_id_seq, docto FROM `t_base` group by docto) t2
    ON     t1.docto = t2.docto GROUP BY t2.max_id_seq, t1.docto
) tb ON ta.id_seq = tb.max_id_seq;

+--------+---------------+-----+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+-----+-----------+-----+
| id_seq | status        | Aut | docto              | fdocto     | nombre             | rfc      | imp | descarea  | cnt |
+--------+---------------+-----+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+-----+-----------+-----+
| 600205 | Pago a plazos | SSA | RDAC9871-874446    | 2008-09-17 | Manuel Rodríguez   | RDAC987  | 500 | Queretaro |   5 |
| 600305 | Pago a plazos | DDA | JMZN987O87-987456A | 2008-09-17 | Juan Manzano       | JMZN987O | 500 | Monterrey |   4 |
| 606207 | Pago a plazos | LLA | EIVC98745-245      | 2008-09-17 | Cristian Enríquez  | EIVC981  | 500 | Nayarit   |   6 |
+--------+---------------+-----+--------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+-----+-----------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```